# Host a l2tp vpn from windows 10

Tags: windows-10, vpn

Is it possible to host an l2tp vpn on a windows 10 computer. I am looking for a way to host an l2tp vpn from my windows computer and (if possible) log all network used and block certain websites. Please help!

Comment: Would you mean host a L2TP VPN server on a Windows 10 machine?

Comment: Yes, I have corrected it

Comment: I'm afraid your goal cannot be achieved. The VPN server must be hosted by Sever since we need configure Routing and Remote Access Service (RRAS) on the server which makes it possible to create applications to administer the routing and remote access service capabilities of the operating system, to function as a network router.